# How to setup yii model relations right, is using 't' to refer to default table a good idea

Tags: yii

Usage of 't' in model relations can give the error

```
"Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.etc' in 'on clause'."
```

It's the usage of 't' to refer to the current table in CActiveRecord Model relations.
I often stumble accross it when using ,findAll, CActiveDataProvider, etc

Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't depending on what model you execute and from where.
I tried using tableAlias but it doesn't work. There must be an easy way.

How can I setup my models and it's relations in such a way that the relations are stable
and always works?

Here is an example of two classes to show the problem...

```
class Order extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'author'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
            'shopproduct'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ShopProduct', 'product_id',
                'with'=>array(
                    'tagsrelations',
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}


class ShopProduct extends CActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'author'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
            'tagsrelations'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TagsRelations','', 
                'on'=>' tagsrelations.tbl_uuid = t.uuid ',
                'with'=>'tag',
                'order'=>'tag.name ASC',
            ),
        );
    }
}


// works
$model=Order::model()->with('shopproduct')->findAll();

// doesn't work
// "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.uuid' in 'on clause'. The SQL statement executed was"
$model=ShopProduct::model()->with('tagsrelations')->findAll();
```

Maybe someone can explain why this isn't working in an understanding way.
How to fix this one once and for all. BELONG TO relations usually work.
What is the best to make an HAS MANY relationship that always works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the `t` only for the join or for some specific purpose? Because for the join this is not the right way to do it. It should be done sth like this:

```
'tagsrelations'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'TagsRelations', array('tbl_uuid'=>'uuid')),
```

Of course you can then add the with condition if you need that as well. But the join should be done this way.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my model(s) based on your new structure. And it seems to work for now. Using an array() like that to connect pk/fk etc directly is a good way. HAS_MANY relations are still problematic  in Yii it seems. I still can't figure it out completely. But this works for now.

Comment: I do not see it as problematic, you just need to know how to define it, but then you don't have any problems

Comment: Perhaps you are right. I found this out. I use **eager loading** most of the time. By using the _loadModel_ in the controller. And then using _User::model()->with('profile, gallery, posts')->findAll();_ like that. But if I remove a relation (HAS_MANY) for example the _posts_ relation. And then automatically the **lazy loading** approach is used in the view. Like in the view there is _$userModel->posts_.  Then I often get some strange errors. I don't know how to make both **eager loading** and **lazy loading** work well.